# Has John Wick ever killed a civillian?

Tags: john-wick, john-wick-chapter-2, john-wick-chapter-3-parabellum

From gunfights within crowded nightclubs, outdoor raves, and busy subway stations John Wick is no stranger to exchanges with a high risk of civilian casualties. I've never seen a noncombatant get injured in one of his many firefights, even though I'd expect bullets to pass through John's original target and into the crowd beyond. The same goes for his opponents, who may not have impeccable aim, but have the common courtesy to avoid shooting innocent people.

Is John Wick such a skilled shooter that no civilian has ever been killed by him?

Comment: An interesting question. But I'd even go as far as posing if there actually *are* any civilians in the world of John Wick (if that hasn't even been asked yet).

Comment: @NapoleonWilson - Wick's wife was a civilian, and Wick himself became a civilian until his car was stolen.

Comment: For interpretations of the word "civilian". Wick was not a civilian, just retired and we know nothing about his wife.

Comment: A combantant is a member of the armed forces of a government with combat duties.  A noncombatant is a member of the armed forces without combat duties, or a civilian, who is defined as someone not a member of the armed forces.  As far as I know all the characters in the John Wick films are civilians, and thus do not have combat roles in the armed forces of any nation, and thus are noncombatants without any legal authorization to fight.  So everyone who shoots in the films should be illegally endangering the lives of civilians.

Comment: I don't want to get too in the weeds on what is a technically a civilian. For the purposes of the question I was just asking if John Wick as ever killed somebody who wasn't his direct target

Comment: @NapoleonWilson raises an interesting point.  I always found it odd how whenever one of those "contract memos" went out, *literally everyone's phone started going off.*  Like, entire city parks or subway stations full of people and apparently *everyone* is on the mailing list for these things...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have watched all 3 Wick movies several times, and in all 3 movies there is never a civilian killed by Wick.  That's not to say that none of them could have been killed, particularly in Wick 2 there are a lot of scenes where Wick misses his target and there are civilians in the area (that whole subway scene shows a *lot* of civilians in close proximity and a *lot* of missed targets), but none of them are shown on screen to have been hit.

Side note: as to the status of Helen, John's wife, I lifted this from the Wiki:

> Bridget Moynahan as Helen Wick: The beautiful wife of John Wick.[17]
> On the character of Helen, Leitch stated, "Helen's the crux of the
> movie, so to have an actress like Bridget come on board in such an
> important role was gratifying. She's got an elegance that is
> captivating." Leitch spoke very highly of Bridget's acting talents and
> when cast in the role of John's wife she decided not to read the
> screenplay, believing that the limited amount of information would
> serve the story well. Moynahan stated, "There was a large portion of
> the story that I didn't want to be informed about. I didn't want or
> need to know that side of John. Helen brought love and light and joy
> into his life. Knowing the other side of it would make it a different
> story for me." [18][19] Iwanyk shared Moynahan's sentiments, adding,
> "Helen probably thought John had some skeletons in his closet, but it
> wasn't important. All we know as an audience is that the moment he met
> her, he became a different person. Love changed him."[17]

That remark about "skeletons in his closet" should give an impression that Helen wasn't a hitman.